# jump back to the first non-whitespace character in vim

Tags: vim

I have a file like the following (with end-of-line shown as $)

```
233            $
```

Suppose my cursor is currently at one of the spaces between `3` and $. I want to be able to jump back to 3. Any available keybinding for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`g_`: To the last non-blank character of the line. It's one of the more obscure built-in motion.s

Comment: OP wants to go back to 3. not to the last character

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry: The 3 is the last non-blank character, isn't it?!

Comment: +1 this would be better answer. since no matter where your cursor is (on that line of course), `g_` brings you there.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best you can do is `be`:

b: back to the beginning of the previous word.
e: go to the end of the current word.

Comment: FYI, `ge` does the same. It isn't shorter but it's a single motion.

Comment: `ge` and `be` aren't identical, if the word behind your cursor is a single character, `b` will go to the word and then `e` will go past the word, whereas `ge` will just go to the single character. It's a small distinction, but it makes `ge` a bit more suitable for macros and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your need, use either `ge` or `g_` or even `F3`